# Help with LINQ to Xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I posted another post earlier on on how to transform an XmlDocument with XSLT but maybe it is possible to do with LINQ instead.

I have an XmlDocument that looks something like:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2315</CustomerId>
    <VersionNumber>1</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>2E05DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2316</CustomerId>
    <VersionNumber>2</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>2E05DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2317</CustomerId>
    <VersionNumber>1</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>9995DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
</DocumentElement>
```

Can I, with LINQ, extract one customer element for each unique GUID and get the customer with the highest version number?

I.e. the new/transformed document will look like:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2316</CustomerId>
    <VersionNumber>2</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>2E05DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2317</CustomerId>
    <VersionNumber>1</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>9995DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
</DocumentElement>
```

Thanks in advance.

Update:

So I should do (if I understand you correctly?):

```
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        // Converts the datatable to XML                             
        dt.WriteXml(sw);
        xdoc = XDocument.Parse(sw.ToString());
    }

        var query = xdoc.Root
            .Elements("Customer")
            .GroupBy(x => x.Element("GUID").Value)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByNumberDescending(x =>(int)x.Element("VersionNumber"))
                          .First());
```

I still get the error on GroupBy though, or am I doing something else wrong here?

Comment: Use `XDocument.Parse` instead of `LoadXml` - or even just `XElement.Parse`. If you've taken the latter route, the element itself can be used as `parent`; otherwise you'll need `doc.Root` as `parent`.

Comment: What's the exact error? Do you have `using System.Linq;` in your list of using directives?

Comment: Sorry I deleted the error message when I did the second update. Anyway, the error was that I by mistake was using system.xml.linq (so some linq stuff worked, some didn't) and not system.linq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
var query = parent
    .Elements("Customer")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Element("GUID").Value)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByNumberDescending(x => (int) x.Element("VersionNumber"))
                  .First());
```

Or using [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var query = parent
     .Elements("Customer")
     .GroupBy(x => x.Element("GUID").Value)
     .Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => (int) x.Element("VersionNumber")));
```